# Tone.js not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, web-audio-api

I want to implement a basic Tone Player to load a file from a folder and play it by pressing a button in ReactJS.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tone from 'tone';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import Slider from 'material-ui/Slider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';


let sound = new Tone.Player("kick.wav").toMaster();
export default class App extends Component {

render() {

    return(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div>
                <Slider min={0} max={100} step={10} className = "Slider1Test1" style={{height: 400}} axis="y"/>
                <RaisedButton label="A" className = "RaisedB1Test1" style={{width: 10}}/>

                <Slider min={0} max={100} step={10} className = "Slider2Test1" style={{height: 400}} axis="y"/>
                <RaisedButton label="B" className = "RaisedB2Test1" style={{width: 10}}/>
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
}
```

But this gives an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data modules.js?hash=625032f…:48100 Uncaught (in promise) Tone.Buffer:
>   could not decode audio data: kick.wav

I have tried "./kick.wav", "./kick.ogg", "./kick.mp3". I have tried giving complete paths. I have tried using only web audio by giving XMLHTTPRequest - it is the same error all the time.

I am new to react - please let me know if there is a correct way to do this. Do I need to use componentDidMount? ( I have tried using that as well. Please let me know the correct way to do it).
Thanks

Comment: Where is your kick file located?

Comment: It is in the same folder as the App.jsx file. Does that make a difference?

Comment: If it's in the same folder, then the path should be './kick.wav' which you tried.  There must be some other error... do you have a github repo for this project? I'm interested in solving this problem

Comment: Also, what browser are you using? Some browers don't support certain audio types.

Comment: Hey thanks for the interest. Here you go - https://github.com/agneyakerure/Harman-How-To-Listen

Please feel free to add features if you dont find them in the current version. I havent pushed the current code into the repo.

Also, I have tried using Chrome, Firefox, Chrome Canary - none of them work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using meteor and this is somehow blocking your request to the server to load your file.  The easiest solution is to create a `public` folder in your root directory and place your samples in there.  Then pass in `./kick.wav` to your `Tone.Player` constructor.  The constructor makes a `GET` request under the hood and will find your file automatically.  Along with the changes I had to add this code to play the sample after the buffer had finished loading:

```
const x = new Tone.Player('./kick.wav').toMaster()
Tone.Buffer.on('load', () => {
    x.start();
})
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Stephen! You are the best!

Comment: Life saver. I am not using meteor, just plain React and still getting the same issue. Putting the sounds in a public folder resolved though.